# Flutter permission denied error when i write to my cloud database

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to write to my cloud Firestore but I keep getting this error when I try to write to my database

```
W/Firestore( 6185): (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (ced601a) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The project was disabled or deleted., cause=null}.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see now " the project was disbaled or deleted" it means that the project was closed or you have to change the timestamp: go to:
rules... edit rules and change where you see:

```
match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(xxxx, xx, xx);
and change the date
```

Comment: I changed the reply